# Woocommerce Coupons, Free product on order when code is entered. Possible?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

So as the name suggests I would like to know if its possible to Have a coupon set up on woocommerce that when entered at the checkout it adds in a free product to the order.
Can this be done or is this something woocommerce could not handle.

If anyone knows of any plugins etc I would be extremely grateful

Answer (score 1):

From your question, you are asking if there's a way for users to enter a coupon that when entered gives free products?

It is possible with Woocommerce, out of the box it has it's coupon management. You can even exclude products which is useful!

Read more about this here http://docs.woothemes.com/document/coupon-management/

It's very simple to get up and running!

Comment: Hello. And it is possible that the discount to be a product item? So if user will buy item A, then he will get item B for free, automatically added into the cart.

Comment: I dont think it's possible to do that on Woocommerce out of the box @GrávujMiklósHenrich You might need to do some custom editing on Woocommerce to allow this. The coupon allows for discounting on the cart, product (in the cart), delivery etc. But doesn't allow adding different product to cart on the coupon discount.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is old but figured I would point out there's a plugin available for rather cheap that can handle this. I'm not the author, nor do I use the plugin, but it should take care of this functionality:

http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-free-gift/6144902